# CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in Snowflake

Tags: database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to know how Snowflake reserves timestamp for a record when getting inserted in batch. Let's say that, there is a batch of 1M records, which need to be inserted, the batch is going to take let's say 10 minutes to complete, there are different possibilities -

1. Same timestamp is reserved for all the records in the same batch at the start of batch
2. Same timestamp is reserved for all the records in the same batch at the end of the batch
3. Timestamp is allocated as and when a record is physically handled.

Comment: Why not test it yourself? It would be the aam timestamp at the start of the query

Comment: Yes, I am doing a theoretical analysis of an incremental load data problem, I don't have write access at the moment, so I am not able to deploy a workload and see it myself..

Comment: [Troubleshooting Bulk Data Loads](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-bulk-ts#load-times-inserted-using-current-timestamp-earlier-than-load-time-values-in-copy-history-view)  `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP is evaluated when the load operation is compiled in cloud services rather than when the record is inserted into the table (i.e. when the transaction for the load operation is committed).`

Comment: to translate Lukasz comment, the timestamp is the compile time of the SQL, so option 1